# Is it possible to match paths between two lists of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, path-finding

I try:

```sql
match (a1 {name: "a1"}) match (a2 {name: "a2" }) 
with [a1,a2] as A
match (b1 {name: "b1" }) match (b2 {name: "b2"}) 
with A,[b1,b2] as B
match p=A--B
return p
```

But it doesn't work.

How should I tell it to find any path between the two groups? Yes I can try individual pair of nodes, but the number of combinations I need to try is huge. The Neo4j Cypher Manual of [Cypher path matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/uniqueness/) and [Lists](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/) don't help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing the last part of your query to

```
match p=(A)—(n)
Where n IN B
return p
```

Comment: Using `match p=(n)--(m) where n in A and m in B` works. Thanks